# Cannot set values to variables in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have created a class in my application for the table employees. Here is the class

```
package com.bct.internal.form.model;

public class Employee {
int id;
String name;
int salary;
String designation;



public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public String getDesignation() {
    return designation;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public void setSalary(int salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}

public void setDesignation(String designation) {
    this.designation = designation;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee [ID=" + id + ", NAME=" + name
            + ", SALARY=" + salary + ", DESIGNATION=" + designation  + "]";
}

}
```

And i am passing values for that columns in a controller.

```
    public static final class EmployeeMapper implements RowMapper<Employee> 
    {

    public Employee mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setId(id);
        employee.setName(rs.getString("name"));
        employee.setSalary(salary);
        employee.setDesignation(rs.getString("designation"));
        return employee;
    }   

}
```

But for id and salary "salary cannot be resolved to a variable". 
What is the problem here.. Please help me..

Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it should be

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.setId(rs.getInt("id")); //or (1)
    employee.setName(rs.getString("name"));//or (2)
    employee.setSalary(rs.getInt("salary"));//or (3)
    employee.setDesignation(rs.getString("designation"));//or (4)
    return employee;
```

Comment: Thank u for answering.. I used this and that error gone. But now its showing an error like "Error creating bean with name 'authenticationDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'id'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:"

Comment: you have to mark id as primary key using @Id annotation in your model class.

Answer (score 2):

There are no any id or salary parameters in your mapRow(). You have to get it from ResultSet object.

So, Instead of doing this:

```
employee.setId(id); //or (1)
employee.setSalary(salary); //or (3)
```

try this :

```
employee.setId(rs.getInt("id")); //or (1)
employee.setSalary(rs.getInt("salary")); //or (3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler cannot resolve the symbols `id` and `salary` within that scope. In simplest terms, the compiler does not know what you mean when you attempt to access a memory location at `id` and `salary`.

In your case, you have to use the appropriate `ResultSet` getter methods to retrieve column values from that specific row.

For more information, visit: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

Sajal Gupta has the correct idea